# Can't align input fields with button in navbar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have decided to have a 6/6 column grid layout with Bootstrap and my navbar does have a brand and login fields.

Unfortunately, I can't seem to align the submit button if I place a `help-block` on the password input: http://www.bootply.com/eJ7QMjincO

Here's the code:

```
<header class="navbar navbar-custom navbar-static-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <!-- Brand -->
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-6">
        <!-- Login -->
        <form class="navbar-form navbar-input-group">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="E-Mail">
              <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
              <span class="help-block text-right">Forgot password?</span>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Not sure if [**this**](http://www.bootply.com/WlKyiYEUXF) is what you are looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add:

```
vertical-align: top;
```

To the button.

Example: http://www.bootply.com/WNCOewwnBs

Comment: Althougt this seems to fix the OP problem, it's a bad practice. If he wanted to add some element above the `<input>`, the button will be misaligned again. It's better to wrap all elements inside the `<div class="form-group">`. This way the input fields will be ever aligned with the button.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your HTML in much better way to provide flexibility between devices. Below is the simple example for that.

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-input-group">
    <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-4">
          <input class="form-control" placeholder="E-Mail" type="text">
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-4">
          <input id="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" type="password">
          <label class="help-block text-right">Forgot password?</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
         </div>
      </div>
</form>
```

BootPly: http://www.bootply.com/kroJXdvceD